# Search for URL in excel spreadsheet and print corresponding row using python

Tags: python, excel, string, search

I am very new to coding, I'm trying to write a simple code that searches an excel file to see if it contains certain URL text strings. For example, to find any links containing "www.italaw.com", I search for "italaw" and then want to print the entire corresponding row if the value is found.

Where it finds a matches to the URL I want it to print the entire row for those results in a new excel file.

So far I have as follows:

```
    import xlrd  
    filepath = 'Appended_Reports.xlsx'
    textstring1 = "italaw"
    textstring2 = "worldbank"
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(filepath)
    ws = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
    
    for row in range(ws.nrows):
         target = str(ws.cell(row, 0).value)
         if target == textstring1:
              print(target)
              print(row)

for row in range(ws.nrows):
         target = str(ws.cell(row, 0).value)
         if target == textstring2:
              print(target)
              print(row)
```

I'm a bit lost to be honest and not sure if I'm going about this the right way, I don't seem to  get any hits even though I know the text I'm searchin for is contained in the first column of the spreadsheet, any thought welcome!

Comment: Your comparison criterion is only part of the string(s) you're interested in. Try changing your if statement to:- if textstring1 in target:

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that and it doesn't generate an error but it also doesn't produce any results, although I know it should find matches. I wonder if the use of "italaw" is sufficient as the full URL might be www.italaw.com/case/857 for example and I'm not sure if it can search for characters within a string?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using openpyxl where we open the first sheet in the workbook and search for any cell that contains a substring of 'cash'

```
import openpyxl as xl

wb = xl.load_workbook("Finances.xlsm", data_only=True)

for row in wb[wb.sheetnames[0]]:
    for cell in row:
        if (v := cell.value) and cell.data_type == 's' and 'cash' in v:
            print(
                f'Cell {cell.coordinate} is type {cell.data_type} and value is "{v}"')
```

For this particular spreadsheet, this will reveal:-

Cell A41 is type s and value is "Total cash"

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll take some of this for mine, I get an invalid syntax for "v := cell.value" Should it be "v == cell.value"?

Comment: You'll need to be using Python 3.8 or higher for the so-called 'walrus' operator to work

Comment: How strange, I have 3.9.5

Comment: Did you keep the parentheses?

Comment: yes it's odd I just googled walrus function and it should work